# Orientation form implies $\Lambda^n M$ is trivial

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Say that $M$ is a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold. Is it true that if we have an orientation form (that is, a smooth nowhere vanishing $n$-form) that $\Lambda^n M = \Lambda^n T^*M$ is trivial?

My thinking is that given $\Lambda^n M$ has dimension 1, perhaps we could then show that the orientation form is a basis of $\Lambda^n M$ which would give that it is trivial. Is this the right way of going about this problem, or is there perhaps an easier way to do it?

Comment: What is the definition of a trivial bundle?

Comment: @Deane a trivial bundle is one that is isomorphic to the base product the fiber, i.e $E \cong B \times F$

Comment: Good. Now prove that this holds in this specific situation. Based on what you've written so far, I know that you know how to do this. What you want to work towards is proving stuff like this simply by confirming that the definition holds and having confidence that what you are doing is correct.

Comment: More generally (perhaps this helps your intuition), a rank $1$ bundle is trivial if and only if it has a nowhere-vanishing section.